# How I can develop a login system using React?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm a php developer but I need to create a system in React.js but I have some questions. In php when a user do a login, It works this way using a web api:

**E.g**
User Access the login page **->** Do a request with login and pass to php file **->** php get the request and send the login and pass to the web api **->** web api check if the user is valid and return it to the php **->** Show to the user if the login is valid

if the login is ok, a session is created and the user is redirected to dashboard. Like the image bellow [image]

But I'm confuse about the React, I need to use the node to operate like php? or just the React? My web api is in ASP.NET CORE.

Comment: The first difference is React runs as a client in your browser. PHP is server side code that runs on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can use Node like PHP to do your authenticating and you can use JSON web tokens similar to sessions:

https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Here's an article on securing React with JWT's:

https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/securing-react-redux-apps-with-jwt-tokens-fcfe81356ea0

Edit:

Another option is to password protect the serving of your React application:

```
<?php if(user_is_authenticated){ ?>

<script src="/static/js/your_application.js></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<?php } ?>
```

You would then want to either use the session or a JWT to protect API calls.